# Pandas covert one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas

I am making trouble on this matter. Would like to ask how to convert the following raw data to result data? Thanks

Raw data

| Name | Board | Slot No. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | WD22UBBPe4 | 3 |
| 14 | WD22UBBPd6 | 2 |
| 14 | QWL1WBBPF4 | 3 |
| 14 | QWL1WBBPD2 | 0 |
| 14 | WD22LBBPD2 | 1 |
| 16 | QWL1WBBPD2 | 4 |
| 16 | QWL1WBBPD2 | 3 |
| 16 | WD22UBBPd6 | 2 |
| 16 | QWL1WBBPD2 | 0 |
| 16 | QWL1WBBPD2 | 1 |
| 72 | QWL1WBBPD2 | 0 |
| 72 | WD22LBBPD2 | 1 |
| 72 | WD22UBBPd6 | 2 |
| 72 | QWL1WBBPD2 | 3 |

Result

| Name | Slot 0 | Slot 1 | Slot 2 | Slot 3 | Slot 4 | Slot 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 |  |  |  | WD22UBBPe4 |  |  |
| 14 | QWL1WBBPD2 | WD22LBBPD2 | WD22UBBPd6 | QWL1WBBPF4 |  |  |
| 16 | QWL1WBBPD2 | QWL1WBBPD2 | WD22UBBPd6 | QWL1WBBPD2 | QWL1WBBPD2 |  |
| 72 | QWL1WBBPD2 | WD22LBBPD2 | WD22UBBPd6 | QWL1WBBPD2 |  |  |

Comment: Added a solution, does it work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it

```
df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Slot No.').add_prefix('Slot ').fillna('').reset_index()
```

```
          Name  Slot Board
Slot No.            Slot 0      Slot 1      Slot 2      Slot 3      Slot 4
      0     14  QWL1WBBPD2  WD22LBBPD2  WD22UBBPd6  QWL1WBBPF4  
      1     16  QWL1WBBPD2  QWL1WBBPD2  WD22UBBPd6  QWL1WBBPD2  QWL1WBBPD2
      2     55                                      WD22UBBPe4  
      3     72  QWL1WBBPD2  WD22LBBPD2  WD22UBBPd6  QWL1WBBPD2
```